Not able to launch screen flow from LWC In Community portal
We have existing screen flow in our org which we call on parent object under object specific action. The flow basically creates Child record in the end. Now my requirement is I want to call that flow in Community portal under the Child object as New button. But I could not see any possible way to achieve this functionality. I have referred few links and observed that:
1. We can create Aura component and call screen flow from it and add the Aura component as Global action to Publisher layout.
**Referred Link:**https://jenwlee.com/2018/05/08/invoke-a-flow-from-a-global-action/
The button is visible only in Salesforce but when I try to add Standard Record Create component in Community then the Custom Global Action button is not visible in Community at all!!
2. I create LWC and call Lightning flows from it.
Referred Link : https://www.forcetrails.com/2022/09/call-lightning-screen-flow-inside-lwc.html
After adding LWC to Community, it does not launch Screen Flows at all.
Is there any other workaround where I can call screenflow from Community site?
Migrating Screen flow solution to Lightning component may not feasible option for us.
One approach I tried and it partially works:
I create new Community page and add flow to the content then by using below LWC, I can launch the flow but the problem is it launches in separate screen(Expected behavior) and if I want to click on Cancel/Finish button, how can I navigate back to the correct page?
LWC HTML:
<template>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleFlowPage}>
        <span class="bold-text">New Opportunity</span>
    </button>
</template>

LWC JS:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {
    NavigationMixin
} from "lightning/navigation";
export default class PortalNewOpportunity extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    displayFlow = false;
    handleFlowPage(event){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            name: 'New_Opportunity_Screen_Flow__c'
        }
    });
    }
}

If there's any other way then I prefer not use above approach as I want to display those flow on as popup(Same behavior in SF environment).
Any suggestion here would be helpful.

Why not directly embed the flow in an experience page?

Then the screen flow does not display as popup in community page. In SF environment, it appears as a popup. Behavior in Salesforce & Community environment gets changed.

Make the quick action a flow-based one and it is shown in a modal.
